# How can you reverse the direction of alt-period in Bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, shell, command-history

In Bash, you can press `Alt`-`.` to insert the last argument of the previous command. If you press it multiple times, it cycles through the last arguments of all of the commands in your history. However, sometimes I press it too many times, and I want to reverse the direction of the cycling, hence go forwards. Is this possible?

(i.e. if you reverse-i-search with `Ctrl`-`r`, you can change directions with `Ctrl`-`s`. What is the analogue for `Alt`-`.`?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you supply a negative argument to `Alt`-`.`, it reverses direction. The easiest way to do that (with standard keybindings) is `Alt`-`-` (equivalent to an argument of -1).

So, after one or more `Alt`-`.` keypresses, pressing `Alt`-`-` will cause the next `Alt`-`.` to go in the reverse direction. (Just ignore the argument dialog which appears when you press `Alt`-`-`.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Pressing `Alt`+`-` removes the command-line prompt and inserts `(arg: -1)` instead. The command itself is unchanged.

Comment: Thenext alt-. (with the -1 arg) will go forwards.

Comment: That's great! I've edited the answer to make it a bit clearer. What does `alt`+`-` do exactly?

Comment: @Sparhawk: as I said, `alt` `-` produces an argument of `-1` for the next readline command. Or, more precisely, it starts a negative argument, so `alt` `-`, alt` `2` would produce an argument of `-2`. In the case of `alt` `.`, only the sign of the argument matters, and only if it is negative, so `alt` `-` is sufficient. (The first `alt` `.` handles its argument differently. See the bash manual.)

Comment: Thank you. I often find `man bash` slightly opaque for such situations, but I think it's clarified it a little here.

Comment: Thank you! I have been wondering how to do this for ages.